# Error UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID occurred while committing offsets for group xxx

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

With Kafka client Java library, consuming logs has worked for some time but with the following errors it doesn't work any more:

```
2016-07-15 19:37:54.609  INFO 4342 --- [main] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Marking the coordinator 2147483647 dead.
2016-07-15 19:37:54.933 ERROR 4342 --- [main] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Error UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID occurred while committing offsets for group logstash
2016-07-15 19:37:54.933  WARN 4342 --- [main] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Auto offset commit failed: Commit cannot be completed due to group rebalance
2016-07-15 19:37:54.941 ERROR 4342 --- [main] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Error UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID occurred while committing offsets for group logstash
2016-07-15 19:37:54.941  WARN 4342 --- [main] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Auto offset commit failed:
2016-07-15 19:37:54.948  INFO 4342 --- [main] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Attempt to join group logstash failed due to unknown member id, resetting and retrying.
```

It keeps resetting.

Running another instance of the same application gets errors immediately.

I suspect Kafka or its ZooKeeper has a problem but there's no error log.

Any one who has idea on what's going on here?

This is the application I'm using: https://github.com/izeye/log-redirector

Answer (score 14):

I just faced the same issue. I have been investigating, and in [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2985) thread and in [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-41%3A+KafkaConsumer+Max+Records) wiki you can find the solution.

The issue seems to be that the processing of a batch takes longer than the session timeout. 
Either increase the session timeout or the polling frequency or limit the number of bytes received.

What worked for me was changing `max.partition.fetch.bytes`. But you can also modify `session.timeout.ms` or the value you pass to your `consumer.poll(TIMEOUT)`

Comment: Changing `consumer.poll(TIMEOUT)` will not help in this case. It is not the same as `session.timeout.ms`.