# Kafka Consumer Hangs Indefinitely after Rebalancing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to utilize a kafka consumer library that is prewritten in my organization. It takes JSON data from a Kafka topic and stores it in a Mongo database. While I cannot post this code, it is a very simple architecture that uses Apache Camel routes, then stores consumed messages into Mongo using the Springboot Mongo dependency.

I am running into a situation where when deploying to OpenShift, and scaling up more than 1 pod, receiving the below exception, and then the application hangs without any more input or processing. I believe the failure is happening within the logic that is within the kafka client library(s).

I have tried running two instances of the application locally, under different ports. That works perfectly without error. I have tried setting the heartbeat interval, session timeout, batch size, max fetch bytes, number of concurrent consumers, SEDA mode on/off, and request timeout. Changing those Kafka settings up, down, on, off and undefined, the issues remain.

```
2019-05-23 16:15:51 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - KafkaConsumer[mytopic]] ERROR o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - Error UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID occurred while committing offsets for group mytopic-status
2019-05-23 16:15:51 [Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - KafkaConsumer[mytopic]] ERROR o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - Error UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID occurred while committing offsets for group mytopic-status
2019-05-23 16:15:51 [Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - KafkaConsumer[mytopic]] WARN  o.a.c.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer - Error consuming mytopic-Thread 0 from kafka topic. Caused by: [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException - Commit cannot be completed due to group rebalance]
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed due to group rebalance
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:552)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:493)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:665)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:644)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.onComplete(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:380)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:274)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:320)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:213)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:163)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:358)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:968)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:936)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$KafkaFetchRecords.run(KafkaConsumer.java:132)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
111
```

Comment: which version of Kafka are you using?

Comment: We are using Kafka version 1.1.1

Comment: Check out this answer, the error msg is same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394662/error-unknown-member-id-occurred-while-committing-offsets-for-group-xxx

Comment: also be aware of a couple of issue for mongo and kafka fixed in `2.23.2`, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12344839&projectId=12311211